# What is the integer reference type in C#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to have an integer variable which can be set to null and don't want to have to use the `int? myVariable` syntax. I tried using `int` and `Int16` to no avail. Do I have to use `int? myVariable`?

I mentioned this because in Java there is both an 'int' type (a primitive) and 'Integer' (a reference type). I wanted to be sure that there isn't a built-in integer reference type that I could be using. I'll use 'int?' for what I'm doing.

Comment: ... Why don't you want to use that syntax?

Comment: @Jon, That is like... I want the compiler to know it without me saying it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For info, `int?` / `Nullable<T>` is **not** a reference-type; it is simply a "nullable type", meaning: a struct (essentially and `int` and a `bool` flag) with special compiler rules (re null checks, operators, etc) and CLI rules (for boxing/unboxing). There *is* no "integer reference-type" in .NET, unless you count boxing:

```
int i = 123;
object o = i; // box
```

but this creates an unnecessary object and has lots of associated other issues.

For what you want, `int?` should be ideal. You *could* use the long-hand syntax (`Nullable<int>`) but IMO this is unnecessarily verbose, and I've seen it confuse people.

Comment: IMHO _?_ confusion depends on background - it confuse ruby people. We are using Nullable<T> it googlable and msdnable :) for newcomers

Comment: How would you deal with the scenario where you have an IDictionary<SomeObject, int> which let's say you use as a count for various objects. The code "theDictionary[someObject] = newValue" would not work as the returned value from the indexer call( "[..]" ) is not an object reference to the same value stored in the dictionary's KeyValuePair<SomeObject, int> instance. To increment the counter would you have to remove the KVP and re-add it to write any new values into the KVP? Or is there some other way?

Comment: @Marchy `theDictionary[someObject] = newValue` will work fine; that is assignment to an indexer, which is well-defined and fully supported

Answer (score 8):

Yes you should use nullable types

See [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

```
Nullable<int> Nullable<float>
```

or simply

```
int? float?
```

PS:

If you don't want to use **?** notation or Nullable at all - simply use special structures for such a thing. For example [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx):

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add('intCol',typeof(int));
var row = table.NewRow();
row['intCol'] = null; //
```

Comment: Note that this is not a reference type, as per your link ("Represents a value type that can be assigned null"). But it does answer OP's underlying problem, if not the question in the title.

Answer (score 4):

[Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable(T) struct.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)
Therefore int, int?, Nullable<int> are all **value** types, not **reference** types

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the only way, as Int32/Int16/int is a primitive type (regardless of boxing/unboxing of these).

Answer (score 0):

The `<var>?` syntax makes it nullable. If you dig a bit deeper, you'll see it's just a generic object that gets used.

If you want to do it like C++ you must use unsafe operations. Then, pointers like in C are available, but your code doesn't conform to CLR...

For using pure .NET without pointers, the `?` is the way to go.

Comment: It's not an object, Nullable is a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's why Microsoft added that. People were creating their own Nullable class so they included this pattern in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Nullable<int>` if you hate `?` so much.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a nullable type, i.e:

```
Nullable<int> or int?
```

The purpose of nullable type is, to enable you to assign null to a value type.

From MSDN:

> **Nullable types** address the scenario where you want to be able to have a primitive type with a null (or unknown) value. This is common in database scenarios, but is also useful in other situations.
>
> In the past, there were several ways of doing this:
>
> 1. A boxed value type. This is not strongly-typed at compile-time, and involves doing a heap allocation for every type.
> 2. A class wrapper for the value type. This is strongly-typed, but still involves a heap allocation, and the you have to write the wrapper.
> 3. A struct wrapper that supports the concept of nullability. This is a good solution, but you have to write it yourself.