# The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code insdie my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
            {
AssetCount = new AssetCount() {

                CustomerCount = entities.AccountDefinitions == null ? 0 : entities.AccountDefinitions.Count(),
                RackCount = tms.TMSRacks == null ? 0 : tms.TMSRacks.Count(),
                ServerCount = tms.TMSServers == null ? 0 : tms.TMSServers.Count(),
                CustomCount = tms.CustomAssets==null? 0 : tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => a.Quantity)

            },
```

But currently if any of the Enumerable are empty i will get the following error:-

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type.

Comment: It's because int32 is a primitive type not an object and thus not nullable.
Try what is suggested in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152717/what-is-the-integer-reference-type-in-c).
TL;DR : when declaring RackCount (for example) using either the syntax `int32? RackCount;` or `Nullable<int32> RackCount;`

Comment: You shouldn't have any of those collections be null in the first place.  There shouldn't be any need for those checks.  Keep in mind *null* and *empty* are two very different things for a collection.

Comment: @Grant yes i'm a little tired i've seen that after posting.
I dont' know the comportment of the Sum method. Could it come from an error returning null ?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 You'll get this error when trying to get the sum of an empty collection; you need to ensure that its' non-empty before summing the values.

Comment: so the problem is with the sum ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is probably that the `tms.CustomAssets` collection is empty.
To fix write something like the following:

```
var tmpCustomCount = tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => (int?)a.Quantity);

...
AssetCount = new AssetCount() 
{
...
   CustomCount = tmpCustomCount ?? 0
}
```

Comment: i can not reference the word "let"..

Comment: @johnG right, you actually do not have a query, just put it in a varible before the expression.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. so i can conclude that .count() will work on an empty list while Sum() will not ?

Comment: @johnG `Sum()` returns the same type as the column being summarized but when translated to SQL an empty query returns `null`, and `null` cant be mapped to `int`. I would call this a bug in the provider. (Linq-to-Object on an empty collection returns 0 for example)