# What's the best way to change a value type to a reference type in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference

I have three classes defined as follows:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Base { ... }

public class Foo : Base
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Base Parent { get; set; }

    public int? FooParentId { get; set; }
    public Foo FooParent { get; set; }

    public int? BarParentId { get; set; }
    public Bar BarParent { get; set; }

    public Foo(Foo parent)
    {
        FooParent = parent;
        FooParentId = parent.Id;

        Parent = FooParent; // Now changes to Parent are reflected on FooParent
        ParentId = FooParentId; // Changes to ParentId are not reflected because it is a value type.
    }
    public Foo(Bar parent)
    {
        // Same implementation as ctor(Foo parent);
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is have `Parent` reference either `FooParent` or `BarParent` (Which I believe is fairly simple,) and then have `ParentId` reference `FooParentId` or `BarParentId`. What is the most sane way of making `ParentId` a reference type?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152717/what-is-the-integer-reference-type-in-c) mentions boxing/unboxing of an integer has plenty of problems associated with it.
Is this really a bad solution?

**Edit:**
I should have mentioned that `Foo` and `Bar` are Entity Framework tables. `Foo` is an object that may be the child of either one table or another, and for Entity Framework code-first to generate the table correctly, both `FooParent` and `BarParent` must be defined. Also, the `ParentId` may not refer to `Parent` in its getter. Entity Framework is to blame for this as well. Entity Framework [Reinserts Existing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) when you call `context.Set<Foo>().Add(newItem);`. All Parents that are not null get re-inserted.

Comment: You need to spend some time reading up on value types (not primative, they're called value types) and reference types.  Changing a reference to point to a new reference is changing the *value* of that variable, and will not affect any other variable referring to the old reference.  You're not *mutating* the reference, you're mutating the *variable* to *refer to a new instance*.

Comment: It also seems like poor design to hold onto both an integer ID of the object and the object itself.  The object itself has its own ID value, if you need it, as the object what it's ID is, rather than holding onto a copy.

Comment: Couldn't you just have the properties delegate to corresponding property? `public int? ParentId { get{ return Parent != null ? Parent.Id : (int?)null; } }`

Comment: @Servy I agree, it is poor design. However I'm using EntityFramework and it is required to fix a _different_ design flaw in Entity Framework. Explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hands are tied by EF, you could use a delegate for the propagation of the change of the `ParentId` based on the type that was passed in the constructor.  I don't know if EF will complain about this or not.

For instance, using the `Action<T>` delegate, we can forward the change to the `ParentId` to the corresponding `[Foo|Bar]ParentId`:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Base {  }

public class Foo : Base
{
    private int? _parentId;

    public int? ParentId { 
        get{ return _parentId; } 
        set{ 
            _parentId = value;
            if( OnParentChangeAction != null ) {
                OnParentChangeAction( _parentId ); 
            }
        } 
    }

    public Base Parent { get; set; }

    public int? FooParentId { get; set; }
    public Foo FooParent { get; set; }

    public int? BarParentId { get; set; }
    public Bar BarParent { get; set; }

    private Action<int?> OnParentChangeAction{ get; set; }

    public Foo(Foo parent)
    {
        FooParent = parent;
        FooParentId = parent.Id;

        Parent = FooParent;
        ParentId = FooParentId;
        OnParentChangeAction = newParentId => FooParentId = newParentId;
    }
    public Foo(Bar parent)
    {
        BarParent = parent;
        BarParentId = parent.Id;

        Parent = BarParent; 
        ParentId = BarParentId; 
        OnParentChangeAction = newParentId => BarParentId = newParentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have here is conceptually an event.  You'll find it best to use a C# `event` to emulate a conceptual events than a delegate as a property.

Comment: Why is it "best" to use an `event` if you're using none of the functionality provided by events, such as multicasting?  If this was a publicly exposed property, I would agree, but this is an private member, and an `event` is overkill.

Comment: Multicasting isn't a property of `event`, it's a property of delegates.  *All* delegates in C# are multicast delegates.  The delegate your using there is a multicast delegate.  One of the primary reasons to use an `event` would be so that the code semantically resembles what your requirements are.  When the code conveys its meaning more effectively it's easier for others to understand it.

Comment: The use of standard delegates in a multicast fashion is exceeding rare. Events provide publisher/subscriber semantics which don't make sense when confined to the declaring type.  Not to mention all of the ceremony required for events. You'd need to create an `EventArgs` class to pass the data to the handler.  You'd need to include the `sender` even though it's all within the declaring type.  Guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: No, you would *not* need to do *either* of those things.  The extent of the change would be to change the declaration of the line to: `private event Action<int?> ParentChanged;` and done.  It would be best to change the event subscriptions from `=` to `+=` as well.  Nothing more needs to be changed.  You add the `event` keyword and remove the property accessor definitions (which of course don't really need to be there for an entirely private member to begin with).  I would also change the name, as per convention, but that's not *required*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have reference to parent object, you can get its Id with property:

```
    public int? ParentId 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Parent != null ? Parent.Id : null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, however unfortunately it will not work for me. Entity Framework requires that the ParentId be decoupled from the Parent reference.

It is explained in greater detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to `get` and `set` accessors of your `FooParentId` and `BarParentId` properties, but agree with @Servy that it's a poor design.

And the reason is even not only having both ID-s and refernce to objects. I don't understand why would you need to have both BarParent and FooParent, just have 1 property of type `IParent` and then communicate with it using methods that this interface provides utilizing all benefits of inheritance and polymorphism.